# Knockout custom computed looses validation rules

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I've created a custom function as seen below. It works perfekt while storing data and updating the observable *MetaData* values etc, but it breaks when it comes to validation.

I am using Knockout validation and have been debugging for a few hours and what I THINK i found out is the fact that the validation is run twice and the second time, all the rules of my observable has dropped, so every time the observable is valid, since there are no rules. The later code is copied from the source code here: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Dist/knockout.validation.js

Why are my custom function making the observable dropping the validation rules?

**My custom function**

```
ko.observable.fn.valueByKey = function (key) {
    return ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var md = ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.unwrap(this), function (item) {
                return item.Key() == key;
            });

            if (md === null) {
                md = new MetaData({ Key: key });
                this.push(md);
            }

            return md.Value();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            var md = ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.unwrap(this), function (item) {
                return item.Key() == key;
            });

            md.Value(value);
        }
    }, this);
};
```

**Code that runs twice**

```
var h_obsValidationTrigger = ko.computed(function () {
                var obs = observable(),
                    ruleContexts = observable.rules();
                console.log(ruleContexts);
                exports.validateObservable(observable);
                return true;
            });
```

**Another important part of knockout validation js**

```
addRule: function (observable, rule) {
                observable.extend({ validatable: true });

                //push a Rule Context to the observables local array of Rule Contexts
                observable.rules.push(rule);

                return observable;
            },
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I've come up with a simple solution that almost seems to work.

```
ko.observable.fn.valueByKey = function (key) {
    var md = ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.unwrap(this), function (item) {
        return item.Key() == key;
    });

    if (md === null) {
        md = new MetaData({ Key: key });
        this.push(md);
    }
    return md.Value;
}
```

When using this, I get validation message on the element, but error-count does not rise on my view model, so the viewmodel it self is still valid, even though i get validation error.

Comment: can u put up a fiddle?

Comment: Here is working JsFiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4h9pjun9/2/
I've set max to 24, but you can still write 58 with keyboard and validation does not warn

Comment: why have you defined min and max values directly on input? From where are you referring this example?

Comment: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation#html5-validation-attributes

Comment: I updated my fiddle with a working example aswell, that uses a "normal" observable, and not a custom one, and it works like a charm.

Comment: where is it? i cant see it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4h9pjun9/6/ Of course i missed to add it, and I cannot edit my comment? Well, here it is!

Comment: what do you think of this? http://jsfiddle.net/LYP5u/309/

Comment: I think you misread the question. Using a normal observable is no problem, as you might see in my fiddle. The problem is when I'm using my own, custom made observable to read the data from a "metadata" array.

Comment: Oh sorry. But why you need your own custom made observable? I am bit curious. I am not so expert but trying to help you out

Comment: Oh, once again i misspoke, i have a custom function, not a custom observable, named valueByKey. I've changed in the thread.